# Create a new document from SharePoint using column data and Quick Parts

Tags: document, column-data, quick-parts

I have a document library with a document template (docx) in which several Quick Parts are defined. The Quick Parts link to column data in the document library.

How do I create the document by filling in the  column data on a NewForm, thus without opening the document template itself?

Thus:
Click new -> go to a page with the NewForm -> fill in the fields -> click OK -> Voila a new Document in the library with the provided metadata.

Comment: im not entirely sure what the question is here. Could you try to elaborate a bit on what you want to achieve? That will help us answer your question.

Comment: @Anders: I believe it's filling in a SharePoint "new form" to create a document populated with metadata. That is, never having to open that document in Word to do fill in the metadata properties.

Comment: Maybe if i rephrase my Question my intentions become more clear:
How to create a new document based on data in a SharePoint list and a document template.
Think of an invoice-generator: Start with a list with invoice data and a invoice-document-template; generate a new Invoice and store it for later use.

Comment: @Dribbel: This isn't possible out-of-the-box. Are you able to use custom development as an option?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using SharePoint Designer workflow and quick parts in Word. OK, this is what you do. Create a document template and save it. Then add it to a document library as a content type. Then create the document library columns that you want popluated. Once this is done, edit the word document from SharePoint and in the quick part fields you will see the columns/fields you created in the library. Once the fields/quick parts have been added to your document save and close. Nw open up SP Designer and create a workflow on that list. You will see a workflow action to create a list item/this is also a document. Select the content type and add the desired fields that you added into the word document as quick part fields.
Now when the workflow runs (after a user has created an item and populated fieds/metadata, the workflow will build the document and populate the fields from the item into the word document. You can also set the create a list item to create the item in another list. Just make sure the destination list as the content type template (with quiick parts) + columns as the source list.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this. The New item form is just an asxp page that allows you to enter data about the file in the library. The file needs to get created somehow and you will have to open the application to make the file, sharepoint won't do this for you. In your example, an Invoice could be either an InfoPath form (preferable) or a Word Document (less preferable).

HTH
Dean

Answer (score 1):

You can create new document with the help of SharePoint workflow. Built-in activities has no functionality for Office documents processing, but you can try to do it with our product:

http://www.harepoint.com/Products/HarePointWorkflowExtensions/

We have the set of 170 ready to use workflow actions that can do anything ;)

WBR, Alexander

Answer (score -1):

To create a document library, follow these steps:

1)    Open a browser and log into Sharepoint.

2)    Click Site Actions and select More Options…Check this helpful link too.......

http://mindstick.com/Articles/19b8cf75-6d2e-4504-8840-718717bd53ba/?Create%20a%20Document%20in%20SharePoint%20and%20add%20folder%20in%20SharePoint%20Document%20using%20C

Its also having with wonderful explanation on Create a Document in SharePoint and add folder in SharePoint Document using C#.

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you read my question carefully? I'm fully aware on how to create a new document library and documents. I want to know how I can get SharePoint to generate a document for me, based on some other data already in SharePoint.