# Autopopulate a word doc template with information from a form Sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, form, word, template

Is there a way to populate fields in a word doc template with information from a form in Sharepoint 2010 so that a user could print out that information in the word doc templates format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved in a roundabout manner by adding quick parts inside a Word document template, adding that template to a content type in a library, linking those quick parts to columns in the library, then creating items (documents) in that library via a workflow (which can be triggered from your source list).

Check out Darren Jones's answer here: [Create a new document from Sharepoint using column data and Quick Parts](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/1282/create-a-new-document-from-sharepoint-using-column-data-and-quick-parts#43441)